# Does echo -e make a difference when quotes are not used?

Tags: echo, escape-characters

If yes, when?
Can anyone explain this?

```
echo -e \tr\t\e\\re\e
#eete 
echo \tr\t\e\\re\e
#trte\ree
```

Answer (score 3):

This has all to do with how the shell parses the command, and little to do with `echo` itself. Take your first example:

```
echo -e \tr\t\e\\re\e
```

Because the backslashes appear outside quotes, the shell will interpret those backslashes as escape marks that remove any special (to the shell) meaning of the character following the backslash. The shell parses this line of code into three words: `echo`, `-e` and `trte\ree`. The first word becomes the command to execute while the latter two become its arguments; the parsed arguments are the only thing `echo` sees. Because the `-e` option was given, the `echo` command will interpret escapes as usual, but in the string `trte\ree`, because that is what the shell passed to it.

Putting the second argument in single quotes prevents the shell from interpreting the `\` character, allowing it to be passed to `echo` verbatim. And thus with this:

```
echo -e '\tr\t\e\\re\e'
```

the shell will invoke `echo` with first argument `-e` and second argument `\tr\t\e\\re\e`. It is now up to `echo` to interpret all the escape sequences.

Answer (score 2):

`\` *is* a quoting operator of the shell. `\x` is like `'x'` in that it removes the special meaning of `x` (except when `x` is the newline character which it removes instead).

So:

```
echo -e \tr\t\e\\re\e
```

is like:

```
echo -e 't'r't''e''\'re'e'
```

None of `t`, `r`, `e` are special in the shell syntax. `\` is the only special one there. So in essence, that's equivalent to:

```
echo -e trte'\'ree
```

Or:

```
echo -e 'trte\ree'
```

Your `echo` implementation seems to be one of those that accepts a `-e` option to tell it to interpret ANSI C escape sequences, so it converts `\r` to a carriage return character, which is a control character which when sent to a terminal tells it to move the cursor back to the beginning of the line, so you see `eete` (that is `trte` partly overwritten with `ee`), and `trte\ree` without.

If you wanted an argument containing `\tr\t\e\\re\e` to be passed to `echo -e`, so that it outputs `<TAB>r<TAB><ESC>\e<ESC>`, you'd need to quote/escape the backslash characters so that they be not interpreted as quoting operator by the shell with either of:

```
echo -e '\tr\t\e\\re\e'
echo -e \\tr\\t\\e\\\\re\\e
echo -e "\\tr\\t\\e\\\\re\\e" # (\ is still special within "..." to escape
                              # the few characters that are still special
                              # to the shell within double quotes)
echo -e $'\\tr\\t\\e\\\\re\\e' # (\ is not a quoting operator in $'...'
                               # but has its own special meaning there
                               # similar to that it has for echo)
```

Or you could do:

```
echo $'\\tr\\t\\e\\\\re\\e'
```

Where this time the `$'...'` expands those `\t`, `\e`, `\r`, `\\` into TAB, ESC, CR, \ respectively so `echo` receives an argument that contains `<TAB>r<TAB><ESC>\e<ESC>`, which without `-e`, your `echo` would display as-is (though note that it's not the case of all `echo` implementations as many do the `-e` interpretation by default (which with some can be disabled with `-E`)).

Comment: Okay, so generally, without quotes, echo -e makes no difference? As in, it shouldn't treat anything as special?

Comment: @SwaroopJoshi, the only thing that `echo -e` treats as special is the backslash character (at least when followed by some of those characters that make up the escape sequences that it recognises). Quoting is about shell syntax, it has little to do with the `echo` command itself.

Comment: but echo -e doesn't seem to work when I don't use quotes. Like `echo -e \tabc\n` just gives tabcn. But when we use quotes, it implements new line and all that. So it must have something to do with quotes, isn't it?

Comment: @SwaroopJoshi, again with a `echo -e \tabc\n` shell command line, which is equivalent to a `echo -e 'tabcn'` command line, the argument `echo` receives is `tabcn`, there's no `\x` sequence in there for it to expand.

Comment: You're right. I had a misunderstanding. Thank you for clearing it